In iOS APP charts are going up and down of the Frame
I am using Combined chart in the react native chart wrapper. I am uploading my candlestick js file as attachement. all wroks fine in android but in iOS APP charts are going up and down of the Frame, while they are not going up and down at the android. i can't figure out it.
https://github.com/user-attachments/files/15507630/CandleStick.zip
Specifications
Version:0.6.0
Platform:ios
I am trying to fix for ios issues and i want ios app chart not going up and down like android app same.

in only iOS app, X axis and Y axis values is being changed continuously even though there is not action by user.
